# fetch all the class attributes with jquery

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="content-1"></div>
<div class="content-2"></div>
<div class="content-1"></div>
<div class="content-3"></div>
```

I want to select all the numbers from the class names , e.g. :1,2,1,3
Should I try `$('div.content').each()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var numbers = $("div[class^='content-']").map(function () {
    return this.className.split("-")[1];
}).get();
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/TECRJ/)

Comment: If the elements have several classes, this should work as well: `$('div').map(function() if(/\bcontent-\d+\b/.test(this.className) { return this.className.match(/\bcontent-(\d+)\b/)[1]; }}).get()` or something similar to that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var numbers = [];

$("div[class^='content-']").each(function() {
   numbers.push(this.className.split('-')[1]);
});
```

Comment: The elements have no class `content`.

Comment: You're right, was looking at the OP's each() example and missed that, changed it but karim was faster then me anyway,

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'split' function and get the number from the class name.

```
        $("div").each(function(e){
            var classNum = $(this).attr("class").split("-");
            console.log(classNum[1]);               

        });
```